# Deleting doubles

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to keep unique case on a dataframe in R.

| Var1 | Var2 | n.call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nigeria | bangladesh | 308 |
| united kingdom | france | 317 |
| nigeria | niger | 574 |
| bangladesh | nigeria | 308 |
| niger | nigeria | 574 |
| romania | oman | 480 |
| oman | romania | 480 |
| france | united kingdom | 317 |

The doubles are slightly different: `Nigeria;Niger` and `Niger;Nigeria`. I would like to delete only one.

dput of my dataframe:

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(111L, 156L, 111L, 13L, 110L, 
123L, 113L, 53L), levels = c("afghanistan", "albania", "algeria", 
"andorra", "angola", "argentina", "armenia", "australia", "austria", 
"azerbaijan", "bahamas", "bahrain", "bangladesh", "barbados", 
"belarus", "belgium", "belize", "benin", "bhutan", "bolivia", 
"botswana", "brazil", "bulgaria", "burkina faso", "burundi", 
"cambodia", "cameroon", "canada", "cape verde", "central african republic", 
"chad", "chile", "china", "colombia", "costa rica", "côte d’ivoire", 
"croatia", "cuba", "cyprus", "denmark", "djibouti", "dominica", 
"dominican republic", "ecuador", "egypt", "el salvador", "equatorial guinea", 
"eritrea", "estonia", "ethiopia", "fiji", "finland", "france", 
"gabon", "gambia", "georgia", "germany", "ghana", "greece", "guatemala", 
"guinea", "guyana", "haiti", "honduras", "hungary", "iceland", 
"india", "indonesia", "iran", "iraq", "ireland", "israel", "italy", 
"jamaica", "japan", "jordan", "kazakhstan", "kenya", "kosovo", 
"kuwait", "kyrgyzstan", "latvia", "lebanon", "lesotho", "liberia", 
"libya", "liechtenstein", "lithuania", "luxembourg", "madagascar", 
"malawi", "malaysia", "maldives", "mali", "malta", "mauritania", 
"mauritius", "mexico", "moldova", "monaco", "mongolia", "montenegro", 
"morocco", "mozambique", "namibia", "nepal", "netherlands", "new zealand", 
"nicaragua", "niger", "nigeria", "norway", "oman", "pakistan", 
"palestinian territories", "panama", "paraguay", "peru", "philippines", 
"poland", "portugal", "qatar", "romania", "russia", "rwanda", 
"san marino", "saudi arabia", "senegal", "serbia", "seychelles", 
"sierra leone", "singapore", "slovakia", "slovenia", "somalia", 
"south africa", "south sudan", "spain", "sri lanka", "sudan", 
"suriname", "sweden", "switzerland", "syria", "tajikistan", "tanzania", 
"thailand", "timor-leste", "togo", "tunisia", "turkey", "turkmenistan", 
"uganda", "ukraine", "united arab emirates", "united kingdom", 
"united states", "uruguay", "uzbekistan", "venezuela", "western sahara", 
"yemen", "yugoslavia", "zambia", "zimbabwe", "ID"), class = "factor"), 
    Var2 = structure(c(13L, 53L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 113L, 123L, 
    156L), levels = c("afghanistan", "albania", "algeria", "andorra", 
    "angola", "argentina", "armenia", "australia", "austria", 
    "azerbaijan", "bahamas", "bahrain", "bangladesh", "barbados", 
    "belarus", "belgium", "belize", "benin", "bhutan", "bolivia", 
    "botswana", "brazil", "bulgaria", "burkina faso", "burundi", 
    "cambodia", "cameroon", "canada", "cape verde", "central african republic", 
    "chad", "chile", "china", "colombia", "costa rica", "côte d’ivoire", 
    "croatia", "cuba", "cyprus", "denmark", "djibouti", "dominica", 
    "dominican republic", "ecuador", "egypt", "el salvador", 
    "equatorial guinea", "eritrea", "estonia", "ethiopia", "fiji", 
    "finland", "france", "gabon", "gambia", "georgia", "germany", 
    "ghana", "greece", "guatemala", "guinea", "guyana", "haiti", 
    "honduras", "hungary", "iceland", "india", "indonesia", "iran", 
    "iraq", "ireland", "israel", "italy", "jamaica", "japan", 
    "jordan", "kazakhstan", "kenya", "kosovo", "kuwait", "kyrgyzstan", 
    "latvia", "lebanon", "lesotho", "liberia", "libya", "liechtenstein", 
    "lithuania", "luxembourg", "madagascar", "malawi", "malaysia", 
    "maldives", "mali", "malta", "mauritania", "mauritius", "mexico", 
    "moldova", "monaco", "mongolia", "montenegro", "morocco", 
    "mozambique", "namibia", "nepal", "netherlands", "new zealand", 
    "nicaragua", "niger", "nigeria", "norway", "oman", "pakistan", 
    "palestinian territories", "panama", "paraguay", "peru", 
    "philippines", "poland", "portugal", "qatar", "romania", 
    "russia", "rwanda", "san marino", "saudi arabia", "senegal", 
    "serbia", "seychelles", "sierra leone", "singapore", "slovakia", 
    "slovenia", "somalia", "south africa", "south sudan", "spain", 
    "sri lanka", "sudan", "suriname", "sweden", "switzerland", 
    "syria", "tajikistan", "tanzania", "thailand", "timor-leste", 
    "togo", "tunisia", "turkey", "turkmenistan", "uganda", "ukraine", 
    "united arab emirates", "united kingdom", "united states", 
    "uruguay", "uzbekistan", "venezuela", "western sahara", "yemen", 
    "yugoslavia", "zambia", "zimbabwe", "ID"), class = "factor"), 
    n.call = c(308L, 317L, 574L, 308L, 574L, 480L, 480L, 317L
    )), out.attrs = list(dim = c(166L, 166L), dimnames = list(
    Var1 = c("Var1=afghanistan", "Var1=albania", "Var1=algeria", 
    "Var1=andorra", "Var1=angola", "Var1=argentina", "Var1=armenia", 
    "Var1=australia", "Var1=austria", "Var1=azerbaijan", "Var1=bahamas", 
    "Var1=bahrain", "Var1=bangladesh", "Var1=barbados", "Var1=belarus", 
    "Var1=belgium", "Var1=belize", "Var1=benin", "Var1=bhutan", 
    "Var1=bolivia", "Var1=botswana", "Var1=brazil", "Var1=bulgaria", 
    "Var1=burkina faso", "Var1=burundi", "Var1=cambodia", "Var1=cameroon", 
    "Var1=canada", "Var1=cape verde", "Var1=central african republic", 
    "Var1=chad", "Var1=chile", "Var1=china", "Var1=colombia", 
    "Var1=costa rica", "Var1=côte d’ivoire", "Var1=croatia", 
    "Var1=cuba", "Var1=cyprus", "Var1=denmark", "Var1=djibouti", 
    "Var1=dominica", "Var1=dominican republic", "Var1=ecuador", 
    "Var1=egypt", "Var1=el salvador", "Var1=equatorial guinea", 
    "Var1=eritrea", "Var1=estonia", "Var1=ethiopia", "Var1=fiji", 
    "Var1=finland", "Var1=france", "Var1=gabon", "Var1=gambia", 
    "Var1=georgia", "Var1=germany", "Var1=ghana", "Var1=greece", 
    "Var1=guatemala", "Var1=guinea", "Var1=guyana", "Var1=haiti", 
    "Var1=honduras", "Var1=hungary", "Var1=iceland", "Var1=india", 
    "Var1=indonesia", "Var1=iran", "Var1=iraq", "Var1=ireland", 
    "Var1=israel", "Var1=italy", "Var1=jamaica", "Var1=japan", 
    "Var1=jordan", "Var1=kazakhstan", "Var1=kenya", "Var1=kosovo", 
    "Var1=kuwait", "Var1=kyrgyzstan", "Var1=latvia", "Var1=lebanon", 
    "Var1=lesotho", "Var1=liberia", "Var1=libya", "Var1=liechtenstein", 
    "Var1=lithuania", "Var1=luxembourg", "Var1=madagascar", "Var1=malawi", 
    "Var1=malaysia", "Var1=maldives", "Var1=mali", "Var1=malta", 
    "Var1=mauritania", "Var1=mauritius", "Var1=mexico", "Var1=moldova", 
    "Var1=monaco", "Var1=mongolia", "Var1=montenegro", "Var1=morocco", 
    "Var1=mozambique", "Var1=namibia", "Var1=nepal", "Var1=netherlands", 
    "Var1=new zealand", "Var1=nicaragua", "Var1=niger", "Var1=nigeria", 
    "Var1=norway", "Var1=oman", "Var1=pakistan", "Var1=palestinian territories", 
    "Var1=panama", "Var1=paraguay", "Var1=peru", "Var1=philippines", 
    "Var1=poland", "Var1=portugal", "Var1=qatar", "Var1=romania", 
    "Var1=russia", "Var1=rwanda", "Var1=san marino", "Var1=saudi arabia", 
    "Var1=senegal", "Var1=serbia", "Var1=seychelles", "Var1=sierra leone", 
    "Var1=singapore", "Var1=slovakia", "Var1=slovenia", "Var1=somalia", 
    "Var1=south africa", "Var1=south sudan", "Var1=spain", "Var1=sri lanka", 
    "Var1=sudan", "Var1=suriname", "Var1=sweden", "Var1=switzerland", 
    "Var1=syria", "Var1=tajikistan", "Var1=tanzania", "Var1=thailand", 
    "Var1=timor-leste", "Var1=togo", "Var1=tunisia", "Var1=turkey", 
    "Var1=turkmenistan", "Var1=uganda", "Var1=ukraine", "Var1=united arab emirates", 
    "Var1=united kingdom", "Var1=united states", "Var1=uruguay", 
    "Var1=uzbekistan", "Var1=venezuela", "Var1=western sahara", 
    "Var1=yemen", "Var1=yugoslavia", "Var1=zambia", "Var1=zimbabwe", 
    "Var1=ID"), Var2 = c("Var2=afghanistan", "Var2=albania", 
    "Var2=algeria", "Var2=andorra", "Var2=angola", "Var2=argentina", 
    "Var2=armenia", "Var2=australia", "Var2=austria", "Var2=azerbaijan", 
    "Var2=bahamas", "Var2=bahrain", "Var2=bangladesh", "Var2=barbados", 
    "Var2=belarus", "Var2=belgium", "Var2=belize", "Var2=benin", 
    "Var2=bhutan", "Var2=bolivia", "Var2=botswana", "Var2=brazil", 
    "Var2=bulgaria", "Var2=burkina faso", "Var2=burundi", "Var2=cambodia", 
    "Var2=cameroon", "Var2=canada", "Var2=cape verde", "Var2=central african republic", 
    "Var2=chad", "Var2=chile", "Var2=china", "Var2=colombia", 
    "Var2=costa rica", "Var2=côte d’ivoire", "Var2=croatia", 
    "Var2=cuba", "Var2=cyprus", "Var2=denmark", "Var2=djibouti", 
    "Var2=dominica", "Var2=dominican republic", "Var2=ecuador", 
    "Var2=egypt", "Var2=el salvador", "Var2=equatorial guinea", 
    "Var2=eritrea", "Var2=estonia", "Var2=ethiopia", "Var2=fiji", 
    "Var2=finland", "Var2=france", "Var2=gabon", "Var2=gambia", 
    "Var2=georgia", "Var2=germany", "Var2=ghana", "Var2=greece", 
    "Var2=guatemala", "Var2=guinea", "Var2=guyana", "Var2=haiti", 
    "Var2=honduras", "Var2=hungary", "Var2=iceland", "Var2=india", 
    "Var2=indonesia", "Var2=iran", "Var2=iraq", "Var2=ireland", 
    "Var2=israel", "Var2=italy", "Var2=jamaica", "Var2=japan", 
    "Var2=jordan", "Var2=kazakhstan", "Var2=kenya", "Var2=kosovo", 
    "Var2=kuwait", "Var2=kyrgyzstan", "Var2=latvia", "Var2=lebanon", 
    "Var2=lesotho", "Var2=liberia", "Var2=libya", "Var2=liechtenstein", 
    "Var2=lithuania", "Var2=luxembourg", "Var2=madagascar", "Var2=malawi", 
    "Var2=malaysia", "Var2=maldives", "Var2=mali", "Var2=malta", 
    "Var2=mauritania", "Var2=mauritius", "Var2=mexico", "Var2=moldova", 
    "Var2=monaco", "Var2=mongolia", "Var2=montenegro", "Var2=morocco", 
    "Var2=mozambique", "Var2=namibia", "Var2=nepal", "Var2=netherlands", 
    "Var2=new zealand", "Var2=nicaragua", "Var2=niger", "Var2=nigeria", 
    "Var2=norway", "Var2=oman", "Var2=pakistan", "Var2=palestinian territories", 
    "Var2=panama", "Var2=paraguay", "Var2=peru", "Var2=philippines", 
    "Var2=poland", "Var2=portugal", "Var2=qatar", "Var2=romania", 
    "Var2=russia", "Var2=rwanda", "Var2=san marino", "Var2=saudi arabia", 
    "Var2=senegal", "Var2=serbia", "Var2=seychelles", "Var2=sierra leone", 
    "Var2=singapore", "Var2=slovakia", "Var2=slovenia", "Var2=somalia", 
    "Var2=south africa", "Var2=south sudan", "Var2=spain", "Var2=sri lanka", 
    "Var2=sudan", "Var2=suriname", "Var2=sweden", "Var2=switzerland", 
    "Var2=syria", "Var2=tajikistan", "Var2=tanzania", "Var2=thailand", 
    "Var2=timor-leste", "Var2=togo", "Var2=tunisia", "Var2=turkey", 
    "Var2=turkmenistan", "Var2=uganda", "Var2=ukraine", "Var2=united arab emirates", 
    "Var2=united kingdom", "Var2=united states", "Var2=uruguay", 
    "Var2=uzbekistan", "Var2=venezuela", "Var2=western sahara", 
    "Var2=yemen", "Var2=yugoslavia", "Var2=zambia", "Var2=zimbabwe", 
    "Var2=ID"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R way.
For each row, sort the first two columns and collapse the rows' results. Then check which of these character strings are `duplicated`.

```r
i <- apply(df1[1:2], 1, \(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ";"))
df1[!duplicated(i), ]
#>             Var1       Var2 n.call
#> 1        nigeria bangladesh    308
#> 2 united kingdom     france    317
#> 3        nigeria      niger    574
#> 6        romania       oman    480
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
df1 <- "Var1    Var2    n.call
nigeria     bangladesh  308
'united kingdom'    france  317
nigeria     niger   574
bangladesh  nigeria     308
niger   nigeria     574
romania     oman    480
oman    romania     480
france  'united kingdom'    317"
df1 <- read.table(text = df1, header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Super smart way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

```
 setNames(unique(cbind(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), df[-(1:2)])), names(df))

        Var1           Var2 n.call
1 bangladesh        nigeria    308
2     france united kingdom    317
3      niger        nigeria    574
6       oman        romania    480
```